# Merge array elements and dedup Mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have below two document on the collection. I need the output grouped by manager level with the list of items assigned under his team.

**Input**

```
{ 
            "emp" : "emp1", 
            "itemList" : [
                "item1", 
                "item2", 
                "item3", 
                "item4"
            ], 
            "reportingTo" : "manager1"
        }
        { 
            "emp" : "emp2", 
            "itemList" : [
                "item5", 
                "item2", 
                "item3", 
                "item4"
            ], 
            "reportingTo" : "manager1"
        }
```

**output:**

```
    {
    "reportingTo":"manager1",
        "itemList" : [
            "item1", 
            "item2", 
            "item3", 
            "item4",
            "item5"
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$reportingTo",
    "itemList": {
      "$addToSet": "$itemList"
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "reportingTo": "$_id",
    "itemList": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$itemList",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$setUnion": ["$$this", "$$value"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```